# Error passing map to template function in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I have been hitting my head against a brick wall for a bit and decided to submit and just post my error.

I have a template (shown below) that passes a std::map, which is inside a namespace. This compiles fine.

My problem occurs when trying to call the function template. I get the below error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 
    'getValuePointer(Muon*&, std::map<int, MET*, std::less<int>, 
                     std::allocator<std::pair<const int, MET*> > >*&)'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the template code:

```
#ifndef OBJECTMAPMATCH_H
#define OBJECTMAPMATCH_H

#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

namespace ObjectMapMatch {


  template< class A, class B, class C >
    C  getValuePointer( A &x , map< B,C> &y )
  {

    if( y.find(x.Index()) != y.end() ){

      return y.find(x.Index()).second;

    }else{
      cout << "ERROR:ObjectMapMatch::getValuePointer:Can not Find " 
           <<  typeid(y).name() << " FOR " << typeid(x).name() << endl;
      exit(1);
    }

  }

}
#endif
```

Here is an example call to the template function

```
C = ObjectMapMatch::getValuePointer<ClassC*, int, ClassD*>(A, B);
```

Where:

```
C is ClassC*
A is ClassC*
B is std::map<int,ClassD*>*
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I constructed a [similar example](http://ideone.com/Relqo), and it runs fine.

Comment: Not a solution, but just a helpful note - unless I'm mistaken, you can use what's called "template type inference" in this case and simplify your function call to `C = ObjectMapMatch::getValuePointer(A, B);`.  The types `<ClassC*, int, ClassD*>` will be inferred automatically

Comment: I would add to Nate, that you not just can, but *SHOULD* use template type inference (applies to function templates only, of course).

Comment: The fact that you use A,B,C with two completely different meanings here, and that you use different class names for the same thing (e.g. Muon and ClassC) makes this question a lot more confusing than it should be.

Comment: @interjay Yes That was stupid of me. Would edit but the answers would then not make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the error message, you passed a pointer to a map as the second parameter, while the function expects a reference to a map.

You can see this because of the `*` at the end here:

```
no matching function for call to 
    'getValuePointer(Muon*&, std::map<...>*&)'
                                          ^
```

There will be additional issues once you fix this though: Since `x` is of type `ClassC*`, calling `x.Index()` will give an error. Maybe the first template parameter should be `ClassC` instead of `ClassC*`.

Comment: A more to-the-point way of saying this is that `B` should not be declared as a pointer.

Comment: @Nate: True, but originally the question said that B wasn't a pointer (which was obviously false). It has been edited now.

Comment: You sir are absolutely right.  Don't know how I missed that. +1 all the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your template definition says:

```
 C  getValuePointer( A &x , map< B,C> &y )
```

And you are calling this function with:

```
ObjectMapMatch::getValuePointer<ClassC*, int, ClassD*>(A, B);
```

... and you say that B is:

```
std::map<int,ClassD*>
```

So, for your template B is an int, and C is a ClassD*... That's why there is not a match.

Or maybe not, I mean, the name you chose for the values is the same for the classes in your template, which is quite confusing.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

your signature is wrong

```
template< class A, class B, class C >
C* getValuePointer( A* x , map<B, C*> &y )
{
    if( y.find(x->Index()) != y.end() ){
        return y.find(x->Index()).second;
    }else{
        cout << "ERROR:ObjectMapMatch::getValuePointer:Can not Find " 
             <<  typeid(y).name() << " FOR " << typeid(x).name() << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

and the call it

```
ObjectMapMatch::getValuePointer<ClassC, int, ClassD>(A, B);
```

but C is ClassD*, not ClassC* right?

Answer (score 0):

In your last edit you say that

```
B is std::map<int,ClassD*>*
```

but your function is

```
template< class A, class B, class C >
C  getValuePointer( A &x , map< B,C> &y )
```

thus accepting

```
std::map<int,ClassD*> &
```

for the second argument. So pointer to map vs. reference to map. I suppose you should either be passing `*B`, or `B` should not be pointer (STL is there so you don't need to work with pointers much so try avoiding them as much as possible).